# Why am I getting r2_score on test set as negative?

Tags: multiple-regression, python, scikit-learn, metric

I wanted to initally test out without dropping any features (Redundant features such as ID are dropped).

data_source -> https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Automobile

This was my procedure:

1) Fit-transform just the numeric variables on train_df (other are dummy/OHE variables)

2) use same scale to transform test_df (just numeric variables)

3) Seperate features and target

Then I did the following:

```
lr_model = LinearRegression()
lr_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
train_pred = lr_model.predict(X_train)
train_score = r2_score(y_train, train_pred)

print(train_score)

>> 0.9823702330232362
```

(everything seems fine till here)

```
 test_pred = lr_model.predict(X_test)
 test_score = r2_score(y_test, test_pred)
 print(test_score)

 >> -2.306048648168645e+24
```

It's very unlikely that the model would do worse than just a horizontal line (predicting same value for all trials).. then why am I getting r2 as negative? Is it just a lack of feature selection (Too much noise in the data)? or am I going wrong else where?

**UPDATE:** After trying the same exact process WITHOUT the scaling I got r^2 of 0.87 makes more sense. How am I scaling it wrong?

Comment: It's not only that $R^2$ is negative, it's also that it is a very large number, on the order of $-10^{24}$. Can you edit your question to post your data?

Comment: Sure. A sample of the main dataset?

Comment: Data that exhibits the problem.